# Win SDK 8.0 Compile Errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-studio-2012, ipc

I am using [simple-ipc-lib](https://code.google.com/p/simple-ipc-lib/) in my project. I have Visual Studio 2012 with Windows SDK 8.0. I also have VS2010 and Win SDK 7.0. I have sometimes installed and uninstalled Visual Studios because of some necessary work.

I have successfully build simple-ipc-lib in VS2012. Its unit-tests are also working fine.

I am now trying to develop an application with it. I made an empty project in VS2012 and included header files and lib. But on compiling it gives me errors

```
1>C:\CEF\simple-ipc-lib\V8_ipc\deps\simple-ipc-lib-read-only\src\pipe_win.h(24): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'fd1'
1>C:\CEF\simple-ipc-lib\V8_ipc\deps\simple-ipc-lib-read-only\src\pipe_win.h(24): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\CEF\simple-ipc-lib\V8_ipc\deps\simple-ipc-lib-read-only\src\pipe_win.h(24): warning C4183: 'fd1': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>C:\CEF\simple-ipc-lib\V8_ipc\deps\simple-ipc-lib-read-only\src\pipe_win.h(25): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'fd2'
1>C:\CEF\simple-ipc-lib\V8_ipc\deps\simple-ipc-lib-read-only\src\pipe_win.h(25): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\CEF\simple-ipc-lib\V8_ipc\deps\simple-ipc-lib-read-only\src\pipe_win.h(25): warning C4183: 'fd2': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>C:\CEF\simple-ipc-lib\V8_ipc\deps\simple-ipc-lib-read-only\src\pipe_win.h(27): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'OpenPipeServer'
1>C:\CEF\simple-ipc-lib\V8_ipc\deps\simple-ipc-lib-read-only\src\pipe_win.h(27): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\CEF\simple-ipc-lib\V8_ipc\deps\simple-ipc-lib-read-only\src\pipe_win.h(27): warning C4183: 'OpenPipeServer': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>C:\CEF\simple-ipc-lib\V8_ipc\deps\simple-ipc-lib-read-only\src\pipe_win.h(28): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'OpenPipeClient'
1>C:\CEF\simple-ipc-lib\V8_ipc\deps\simple-ipc-lib-read-only\src\pipe_win.h(28): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\CEF\simple-ipc-lib\V8_ipc\deps\simple-ipc-lib-read-only\src\pipe_win.h(28): error C2086: 'int PipePair::HANDLE' : redefinition
1>          C:\CEF\simple-ipc-lib\V8_ipc\deps\simple-ipc-lib-read-only\src\pipe_win.h(27) : see declaration of 'PipePair::HANDLE'
1>C:\CEF\simple-ipc-lib\V8_ipc\deps\simple-ipc-lib-read-only\src\pipe_win.h(28): warning C4183: 'OpenPipeClient': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>C:\CEF\simple-ipc-lib\V8_ipc\deps\simple-ipc-lib-read-only\src\pipe_win.h(31): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'srv_'
1>C:\CEF\simple-ipc-lib\V8_ipc\deps\simple-ipc-lib-read-only\src\pipe_win.h(31): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\CEF\simple-ipc-lib\V8_ipc\deps\simple-ipc-lib-read-only\src\pipe_win.h(32): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'cln_'
1>C:\CEF\simple-ipc-lib\V8_ipc\deps\simple-ipc-lib-read-only\src\pipe_win.h(32): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\CEF\simple-ipc-lib\V8_ipc\deps\simple-ipc-lib-read-only\src\pipe_win.h(24): error C2065: 'srv_' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\CEF\simple-ipc-lib\V8_ipc\deps\simple-ipc-lib-read-only\src\pipe_win.h(25): error C2065: 'cln_' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\CEF\simple-ipc-lib\V8_ipc\deps\simple-ipc-lib-read-only\src\pipe_win.h(40): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'HANDLE'
1>C:\CEF\simple-ipc-lib\V8_ipc\deps\simple-ipc-lib-read-only\src\pipe_win.h(41): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'HANDLE'
1>C:\CEF\simple-ipc-lib\V8_ipc\deps\simple-ipc-lib-read-only\src\pipe_win.h(49): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'pipe_'
1>C:\CEF\simple-ipc-lib\V8_ipc\deps\simple-ipc-lib-read-only\src\pipe_win.h(49): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\CEF\simple-ipc-lib\V8_ipc\deps\simple-ipc-lib-read-only\src\pipe_win.h(46): error C2065: 'INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\CEF\simple-ipc-lib\V8_ipc\deps\simple-ipc-lib-read-only\src\pipe_win.h(46): error C2065: 'pipe_' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(46): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'nLength'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(46): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(47): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'lpSecurityDescriptor'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(47): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(48): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'bInheritHandle'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(48): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(52): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Internal'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(52): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(53): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'InternalHigh'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(53): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(56): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Offset'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(56): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(57): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'OffsetHigh'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(57): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(59): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Pointer'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(59): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(62): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'hEvent'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(62): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(66): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'lpCompletionKey'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(66): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(68): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Internal'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(68): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(69): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'dwNumberOfBytesTransferred'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(69): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(80): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'dwLowDateTime'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(80): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(81): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'dwHighDateTime'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(81): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(90): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wYear'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(90): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(91): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wMonth'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(91): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(92): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wDayOfWeek'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(92): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(93): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wDay'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(93): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(94): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wHour'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(94): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(95): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wMinute'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(95): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(96): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wSecond'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(96): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(97): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wMilliseconds'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(97): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(102): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'dwFileAttributes'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(102): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(106): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'nFileSizeHigh'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(106): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(107): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'nFileSizeLow'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(107): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(108): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'dwReserved0'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(108): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(109): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'dwReserved1'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(109): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(110): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'cFileName'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(110): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(110): error C2065: 'MAX_PATH' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(111): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'cAlternateFileName'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(111): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(119): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'dwFileAttributes'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(119): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(123): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'nFileSizeHigh'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(123): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(124): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'nFileSizeLow'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(124): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(125): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'dwReserved0'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(125): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(126): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'dwReserved1'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(126): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(127): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'cFileName'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(127): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(127): error C2065: 'MAX_PATH' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(128): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'cAlternateFileName'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(128): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(198): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'CRITICAL_SECTION'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(198): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(199): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'PCRITICAL_SECTION'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(199): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(202): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'CRITICAL_SECTION_DEBUG'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(202): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(203): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'PCRITICAL_SECTION_DEBUG'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(203): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(208): error C2065: 'WINAPI' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(208): error C2065: 'LPOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(208): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\minwinbase.h(208): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

Separate compilation of Simple IPC lib is doing right. I can not understand the errors in this. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are failing to include a required header file. If that is not the case you probably forgot to terminate a class definition with a `;` character in a header file.

Comment: It must be in my code since separate building of lib is successful. But i do not have any class in my code. I commented everything in the code except the headers and int main(){ // comment_all except return 0; }

Comment: when i comment this #include <WinBase.h> and #include "pipe_win.h" these errors go but other errors come.

Comment: Instead of `#include <WinBase.h>` you should `#include <windows.h>`. Also make sure that it is included prior to `pipe_win.h`.

Comment: Yaa just did it. Errors resolved.

Comment: but linker errors like : >msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Container_base12(void)" (??0_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in ipc_lib.lib(pipe_win.obj) coming.

Comment: set /MTd in compiler options. done.

Comment: It looks like you are building for ARM. Is that correct? I'm experiencing it with `... /DWINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_PHONE_APP` from the command line using VS2012 ARM Developer Prompt. Did you figure out how to work around this issue? `/MT` and `/MD` made no difference for me.